# some error with editing mysql content via php

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, edit, editing

i have some problem

i done my project, but there is problem in it like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'blink = 'asd' WHERE bid='1'' at line 6
>   in editing file for edit my book content

```
    <?php
include("../includes/config.php");
$cuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books");
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$bname = strip_tags($_POST['bname']);
$bpic = strip_tags($_POST['bpic']);
$bdesc = strip_tags($_POST['bdesc']);
$bauthor = strip_tags($_POST['bauthor']);
$blink = strip_tags($_POST['blink']);
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $cuuser = mysql_fetch_object($cuser);
    echo "<form action='editbook.php?edit=yes&id=".$cuuser->bid."' method='POST'>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>bname : </td>
    <td><input name='bname' type='text' value='".$cuuser->bname."' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>bpic : </td>
    <td><input name='bpic' type='text' value='".$cuuser->bpic."' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>bdesc : </td>
    <td><input name='bdesc' type='text' value='".$cuuser->bdesc."' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>blink : </td>
    <td><input name='blink' type='text' value='".$cuuser->blink."' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>bauthor : </td>
    <td><input name='bauthor' type='text' value='".$cuuser->bauthor."' /></td>
    </tr>
    <td><input name='do' type='submit' value='GO' /></td>
    </table>
    </form>";
}
        if($_REQUEST['edit'] == 'yes'){
            $uuser = mysql_query("UPDATE books SET 
            bname = '$bname',
            bpic = '$bpic',
            bdesc = '$bdesc',
            bauthor = '$bauthor'
            blink = '$blink'
            WHERE bid='$id' ") or die(mysql_error()) ;
            if(isset($uuser)){
                echo "done";
            }
        }

?>
```

when i delete (blink = '$blink') from query its will save and edit
but i need it in my project 
note: i change blink for a lot of times and try another names (same problem)

and if there is another way to edit mysql content via php i will be so happy :) anything let my project worked correctly

Thanks :)

Comment: `bauthor = '$bauthor',`, note the comma.

Comment: this isn't a live site I hope

Comment: Its a TYPO, close accordingly

Comment: @Mr.Kmar Btw, what Ray C wrote in his answer is not entirely true/correct. Consult the comments I left under the answer. Don't kid yourself and don't play with security when it comes to the Internet; you will not be happy if/when you do make a live site, believe me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you omitted comma in your update statement after `bauthor` and `blink` line.

Second, I see you did not do any processing for input data. It s very vulnerable for SQL injection. 
Also if someone types quote mark ' inside of input data, your save query will fail, too.
So you should make a fix for this purpose, too.
Simply apply `mysql_real_escape_string` function for each input will save you for saving failure of comma contained string data.

So try following code for fast fix:

```
if($_REQUEST['edit'] == 'yes'){
            $uuser = mysql_query("UPDATE books SET 
            bname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($bname) . "',
            bpic = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($bpic) . "',
            bdesc = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($bdesc) . "',
            bauthor = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($bauthor) . "',
            blink = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($blink) . "' 
            WHERE bid='$id' ") or die(mysql_error()) ;
            if(isset($uuser)){
                echo "done";
            }
        }
```

For better security option, you can try [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with prepared statement.

Comment: +1 Thanks bro about telling me about it, as i say i'm not in securing mode now, i'm just programming and take a lot of times searching for bug in script :) Thanks a lot

Comment: I wouldn't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` yet alone `mysql_*` functions. They're old and deprecated and `mysql_real_escape_string()` can still be open to an SQL injection. *"Simply apply mysql_real_escape_string function for each input will save you."* - No it won't. See the following Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: *"For better security option, you can try PDO."* - Without a prepared statement, PDO alone is still prone to injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your feedback. I updated the content to avoid misunderstanding as it says something different than I meant.